# Is there a library that disable the website on unsupported browsers?

Tags: html, css

I want to disable my website on older version that doesn't support HTML5 and CSS3. Is there any lib or code that can do this?

Comment: no, since both are living standards and html5 from today can be different from html5 tomorrow. same for css3.

Answer (score 2):

[Modernizr](https://modernizr.com) should fit your needs.